# Kotlin+spring+mustache @Controller does not working (Whitelabel Error Page) but @RestController working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mustache

Have some problem with spring on Kotlin. When I set @RestController and go to localhost:8080 then I can see "index". If I set @Controller, I have

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 13 23:34:59 EEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I have no idea why it not working. In java similar code (from tutorial) working. My code based on code in tutorial for java.
My App.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

SomeController

```
@Controller
class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(model: Model): String {
        model["something"] = "asd"

        return "index"
    }
}
```

index.mustache:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    its the {{something}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Why do you think it should work? Where are your views configured?

Comment: Hm... Some guy made tutorial and it works. So I guess it should be working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have template engine added in your pom.xml Add this:

```
<dependency>          
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah. I started write it on Java and after tried move it on Kotlin and add all dependencies and it works. Sorry for stupid question). Anyway thx!